# Value must be keyof keys in object

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Would like to enforce that values point to key of type like so, not sure how best to do it

```
type Graph = {
  [nodeId: number]: Array<keyof Graph>
}

const graph: Graph = {
  0: [1, 2, 3],
  1: [2],
  2: [3],
  3: [1],
}
```

Also tried

```
type Graph = {
  [nodeId: number]: Array<nodeId>
}
```

no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript can't really represent `Graph` as a concrete type.  However, it is possible to represent it as a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) type where the numeric keys `K` are part of the type:

```
type Graph<K extends number> = { [P in K]: K[] };
```

And then you can use a helper function to infer the proper `K` value for a given value:

```
const asGraph = <K extends number, V extends K>(g: Record<K, V[]>): Graph<K> =>
  g;

const goodGraph = asGraph({
  0: [1, 2, 3],
  1: [2],
  2: [3],
  3: [1]
}); // Graph<0 | 1 | 2 | 3>
```

And it correctly rejects bad graphs:

```
const badKey = asGraph({
  zero: [1], // error! "zero" does not exist in Record<number, number[]>
  1: [1]
});

const badValue = asGraph({
  0: [1],
  1: [0],
  2: [8675309], // error! number not assignable to '0 | 1 | 2'.
  3: ["zero"] // error! string also not assignable to '0 | 1 | 2'
});
```

Hope that helps.  Good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#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)

Comment: Hmmm that's a shame TS doesn't support that. Thanks though